# Which linq functions are fully supported by NHibernate 3.0 IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, c#-4.0, nhibernate-3

I have been using NHibernate for a while and loved NHibernate.Linq. Now that NHibernate 3.0 is out with Linq built in, I have been looking for some documentation to find out exactly which Linq functions are suppported now and for some reason cannot find a definative list anywhere.

Short of running a load of code to see "Specified method is not supported." exceptions I was wondering if anyone knows where a list of the supported functions might be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only authoritative source is... the source :-)

https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Linq

Still, if you have specific methods that you need support for, you can always create a Jira issue at http://jira.nhforge.org

BTW, the latest stable version is 3.1, with 3.2 coming soon. A lot of work has been done since 3.0 in the LINQ front (I've submitted a few small patches myself)